# Why is the color for the notification icons generated by Android Image Asset Studio completely white?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

When I right-click on my `drawable` folder and do `New` -> `Image Asset` -> `Notification Icons`, my icon color becomes white. The background of the image I upload is transparent, but why does the icon become white? How do I fix this? I want to keep the original color. My minimum API level is set to 21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [guidelines](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#anatomy-of-a-notification), notification icons are monochrome and tinted via the [`setColor` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(int)), so it is expected that they are a solid white color.

Comment: Can `setColor` be set to an SVG? The color for my icon isn't a simple hex code or an RGB value. It's a mix of four different colors (a gradient you can say).

Comment: That's not supported, no. It is a solid color that is used throughout the entire notification - icon, action text, replies, etc.